# A delicious country puzzle

Tags: word, knowledge, visual, rebus

**Why is this puzzle delicious? Give me the 5-letter answer I'm looking for.**

---

```
                                                            gnramaa
                                                               
                                                               ↓     
                                                               
                            image    (8)     (7)      →      xx?    (6)      x?xx    (4)
```

[image]

```
                                        (4) "+" (6)

                                          (1[5]2)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This puzzle is delicious because it contains a nice, juicy...

> **MANGO**!

First solve the rebus. The words we are looking for, of 8 and 7 letters, are:

> **DIAGONAL ROMANIA**, since there is a diagonal line comprising outlines of the country of Romania.

Now we apply the instruction at the top...

> "xx?" and "(6)" are supposed to be considered together. Each 'x' means 'remove a letter', so if we remove the first two letters of the word DIAGONAL (which would be DI) we end up with AGONAL (a 6-letter word). We now need to **anagram** it (suggested by 'gnramaa' - an anagram of 'anagram'), and we can do this to produce the name of another country: **ANGOLA**.
>
>  Similarly, "x?xx" and "(4)" should be considered together. If we remove the first letter and the last two of ROMANIA (so, the R and the IA) we produce **OMAN**, a 4-letter country...

Finally, we apply the last instruction. If we...

> 'plus' the 4-letter country and 6-letter country together, in that order, we can form an overlapping string of characters: OMANGOLA.
>
>  The final "(1[5]2)" suggests we break up this final string into groups of 1, 5, and 2 letters and focus on that central 5-letter substring, which just *happens* to be the word **MANGO** - so this puzzle both involves countries and also something delicious, hence it being titled 'A delicious country puzzle'!

Comment: That's it, nice job!